# Counting all distinct rows, and then join with another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Every day I check a log file with all information from several wireless networks.  I have made a small `C#/SQLite` app that imports the log file into a database.

I then select (and count) all distinct access points by their mac address, and order them by the count.

I have been able to write a query to solve this, but I struggle to get the access points name from another table.

***Tables***

**issues**

date_time
ap_mac_address
client_mac_address
issue

**ap**

mac 
name

**My query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ap_mac_address as [AP MAC Address],
COUNT(ap_mac_address) as Number
FROM issues
GROUP BY ap_mac_address
ORDER BY Number DESC
```

This gives me the wanted result, but when I try to join this with the name of the access points in the other table, I got stuck.

[image]

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Sorry - English is not my mother language, and I am a programming beginner ...

Comment: The column names in your external link do not match to either of the tables you described in your question.  Please fix your data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following will do what you wish :-

```
SELECT DISTINCT ap_mac_address as [AP MAC Address],
COUNT(ap_mac_address) as Number, Name /* ADDED (including the comma) */
FROM issues 
    JOIN ap ON ap.map = issues.ap_mac_address /* ADDED */
GROUP BY ap_mac_address
ORDER BY Number DESC
```

This does assume that ap is the mac address and is unique.

Comment: That gave me the wanted result!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be more effcient to aggregate *before* the join:

```
select [AP MAC Address], Name, Number
from
 (
   SELECT ap_mac_address as [AP MAC Address],
      COUNT(ap_mac_address) as Number
   FROM issues 
   GROUP BY ap_mac_address
 ) as i
-- Outer Join if there's a mac address not mapped
LEFT JOIN ap ON ap.map = i.ap_mac_address 
ORDER BY Number DESC
```

Btw, GROUP BY is already returning unique data, there's no need for an additional DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

This is a canonical `JOIN`/`GROUP BY` query.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT ap.Name, i.ap_mac_address as [AP MAC Address],
       COUNT(*) as Number
FROM issues i JOIN
     ap
     ON ap.map = i.ap_mac_address 
GROUP BY ap.Name, i.ap_mac_address
ORDER BY Number DESC;
```

Notes:

- Qualify all column names.  That is, specify the table where they come from.
- Use table aliases.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never used with `GROUP BY`.